# How to include css file into a svg file without html

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a svg file and I use javascript to draw the image in a canvas using DrawImage function.
I'm wondering if I can use an external css file in my svg file.
I can't find anything about using an external css file without embeded or without using the svg file as image.

I found that, but it didn't work.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Style.css" ?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="453.96px" height="660.7px" viewBox="0 0 453.96 660.7" enable-background="new 0 0 453.96 660.7" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="Wind">
....
</g>
```

```css
#Wind{
  fill: blue;
  width: 100px;
  color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Simple nice question. Its rare to find these.

Comment: SVG `width` can not be changed in CSS and you can not use `color` in SVG

Comment: Because fill didn't work, I tried a lot of different things, but none works.

Answer (score 1):

I am using something like this:

```html
 <svg . . . . >
  <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
        circle {
          fill: red;
        }
        ]]> 
  </style>
  <circle . . . . />
  </svg>
```

External css file using  @import

```
 <svg . . . .>
  <style>
        @charset "UTF-8";
        @import url(estilosSVG.css);
        rect{fill:#6ab150;}
      </style>
      <rect .../>
  </svg>
```

If you don't want to use @import:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css" ?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  ...................................
```

The `DOCTYPE` part is optional.

Comment: Alright! However, I'm looking for an external css file because I have to change one thing in three different svg files at the same time.

Comment: I've seen those options and I tried them, but they doesn't work.

I'll updated question.

Maybe my css is the issue here.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. Please check this: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/project/editor/91143c063e6b9abf1b5c43a14a9937ea#0

Comment: My guess is when using javascript to draw the svg image the external css doesn't work. However, if the css is in the svg file that works.

Comment: In this case you should update your question by adding the javascript